# nested XML into DataSet

Tags: asp.net, xml, dataset

How do I load the following nested XML into a DataSet?

```
 <Response>
  <Request>
    <Origin>NYK</Origin>
    <Destination>TOK</Destination>
  </Request>
  <Depart>
    <Fare>
      <Chargeable>
        <BaseFare>100</BaseFare>
        <Tax>10</Tax>
      </Chargeable>
      <Nonchargeable>
        <Charge>10</Charge>
        <Add>15</Add>
      </Nonchargeable>
    </Fare>
  </Depart>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the XDocument for read xml,

http://www.xmlplease.com/read-xml-linq